# Upload image - ForeignKey conflict

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc

im trying to use a jquery plugin to upload my images and insert it into my database.

my problem are the relationship i have between the two table.

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Image_User". The conflict occurred in database
>   "Mydatabase", table "dbo.User", column 'Id'.

here is my code:

in controller:

GET:

```
 public ActionResult Manage(int id = 0)
        {
            User u= db.MyUsers.Find(id);

            if (u== null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(u);
        }
```

To upload i have this code:

```
 private void UploadWholeFile(HttpContext context, List<FilesStatus> statuses, Image img, User u)
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < context.Request.Files.Count; i++)
                {
                    var file = context.Request.Files[i];

                    var fullpath = StorageRoot + Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                    file.SaveAs(fullpath);

                    string fullName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    statuses.Add(new FilesStatus(fullName, file.ContentLength, fullpath));

                    SqlCommand cmd;
                    System.Text.StringBuilder sql = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                    sql.Append("insert into Image(MyFileName,Id_User)");
                    sql.Append("values (@MyFileName, @Id_User)");

                    cn.Open();
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), cn);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MyFileName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fullpath;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id_User", SqlDbType.Int).Value = u.Id;

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    cn.Close();
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id_User is in a foreign key relationship with dbo.User table, which does not contain the ID you are trying to insert. Insert the value in the dbo.User table first, or check and correct the value you are inserting in Id_User.

Comment: Please make sure that you are inserting correct value of Id_User in Image table, this value should also present in user table.

Comment: what i can´t understand is. i have a get method which sends the values of my table. and then on upload he can´t get the values of the current id