# How to get the current route id in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

im working on a project in mvc.

what i try to do is to get a the current id of the route to use it in a uploadhandler method to insert into this value into my database:

is it possible to get the current route id in a ashx file in mvc?

i have searching a lot and see some answer like: `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"];`

what im trying to do is like :

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ident", SqlDbType.Int).Value = /*HERE write a line to get the current id*/;
```

Comment: Do you want to create a route to an ashx file?

Comment: @Abbas: i have an ashx file which have an uploadhandler. and one method i specified a sql statement to insert the filename and the id from a table which contains the primary key... the table which contains the filename column have the foreignkey id

Comment: Is there any reason that you have used the ashx; because there are other and simple ways to upload an image. I think your question is a little confusing; please clarify it.

Comment: the reason is because im using a jquery file upload plugin from blueimp.. take a look at this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574329/upload-image-foreignkey-conflict    ... this is another question related to this... which i specified with the completed code what im trying to do

Comment: I understand, have you examined the `ValueProvider` object?

Comment: the value are 0, @Abbas

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try with:

```
Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]
```

Comment: doesn´tcontain a definition for RequestContext

Comment: Are you using the Controller Url helper class?